# In for loop how to check current array value with all previous array in php

Tags: php, arrays

In for loop how to check current value with each and every previous value using php

my array:

In array list  `[prolabelpos] =>0`   having three times, how to execute a `[prolabelpos] =>0` only one time in for loop . how to check current array with all previous value and `[prolabelpos] =>0` execute once in the for loop

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [productlabel_id] => 6 [prolabelpos] => 0  ) 
    [1] => Array ( [productlabel_id] => 5  [prolabelpos] => 6  )
    [2] => Array ( [productlabel_id] => 4  [prolabelpos] => 0 )
    [3] => Array ( [productlabel_id] => 3  [prolabelpos] => 5  )
    [4] => Array ( [productlabel_id] => 2 [prolabelpos] => 0  )
)
```

my code:

```php
<?php  
$prev = null;
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $label_position = $value['prolabelpos'];
    if ($prev != $label_position) {
        echo "my code";
    }
    $prev = $label_position;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to achieve.. You want only one result with `prolabelpos = 0`? What do you want to do with the other cases (where the ID is 4 and 2)?

Comment: previous value of [prolabelpos] =>0   (where id 4 and 2) not need  to execute, i need to execute only higher order id 6 value of [prolabelpos] =>0

Comment: Okay. Then you need to show how you create this array.

Comment: okay wait i will post a  code

Comment: i was post my code  above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this in `foreach` OR `array_map`

```
$arr = 
 Array ( 
 '0' => Array ( 'productlabel_id' => 6, 'prolabelpos' => 0  ),
 '1' => Array ( 'productlabel_id' => 5,  'prolabelpos' => 6  ),
 '2' => Array ( 'productlabel_id' => 4,  'prolabelpos' => 0 ),
 '3' => Array ( 'productlabel_id' => 3,  'prolabelpos' => 5  ),
 '4' => Array ( 'productlabel_id' => 2 ,'prolabelpos' => 0  )
);
$traversed = array();
foreach($arr as $value){
  if(in_array($value['prolabelpos'], $traversed)){
    //This has been traversed before
  }else{
    /* Apply your Logic */
    $traversed[] = $value['prolabelpos'];
  }
}
```

Using `array_map`

```
$arr = Array ( 
  '0' => Array ( 'productlabel_id' => 6, 'prolabelpos' => 0  ),
  '1' => Array ( 'productlabel_id' => 5,  'prolabelpos' => 6  ),
  '2' => Array ( 'productlabel_id' => 4,  'prolabelpos' => 0 ),
  '3' => Array ( 'productlabel_id' => 3,  'prolabelpos' => 5  ),
  '4' => Array ( 'productlabel_id' => 2 ,'prolabelpos' => 0  )
);
$traversed = array();
array_map(function($v) use (&$traversed){
  if(in_array($v['prolabelpos'], $traversed)){
    //This has been traversed before
  }else{
    /* Apply your Logic */
    $traversed[] = $v['prolabelpos'];
  }
}, $arr);
```